# Sign eth transaction in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm newbie in Rust. I tried to sign raw transaction in Rust but I stuck in type. Here is my code

```
use ethereum_types::{U256, H160};

        let tx = ethereum_tx_sign::RawTransaction {
            nonce: U256::from(0),
            to: Some(&to),
            value: U256::from(10000),
            gas_price: U256::from(10000),
            gas: U256::from(21240),
            data: vec![0],
        };

/// Description of a Transaction, pending or in the chain.
#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct RawTransaction {
    /// Nonce
    pub nonce: U256,
    /// Recipient (None when contract creation)
    pub to: Option<H160>,
    /// Transfered value
    pub value: U256,
    /// Gas Price
    #[serde(rename = "gasPrice")]
    pub gas_price: U256,
    /// Gas amount
    pub gas: U256,
    /// Input data
    pub data: Vec<u8>,
}
```

When I run cargo check, I get

```
expected `primitive_types::U256`, found `U256`
```

But I dont know why. Can anyone explain and help me?

Comment: what are your dependency versions? specifically `ethereum_tx_sign` and `ethereum_types`

Comment: @kmdreko thank you for pointing it. ethereum_tx_sign use 0.9.0 version and mine is 0.11.0. How can I fix it?

Comment: use the 0.9 version of ethereum_types